How to perform a long-running task when app starts?
When the configuration changes (for example, the user's number format has changed), all data in the database must be updated.
For this, I added a function to onCreate() that converts all data when the application is launched/recreated. The problem is that the conversion can take several seconds, so an AlertDialog needs to be shown. But the program continues to run and reads the data before it has been converted.
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ///...
   convertDataInDB();
   //How to stop the application from running further before
   //conversion is complete? Otherwise it starts working
   //with old unconverted data.
}

public void convertDataInDB() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false); 
    builder.setView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            db.convertData();
        }
    });
    t.start();  
}

How to implement this correctly?

"How to implement this correctly?" -- store the data in the database in a better way, one that does not depend on the user's choice of number format. Formatting is how you display data. For example, whether the user's chosen thousands separator is , or . affects how you display numbers, but it should not affect how you store numbers. If you do this, "all data in the database must be updated" goes away.

@CommonsWare, thank you very much for the advice! I went the wrong way. Now I have abandoned the idea of ​​updating the format in the DB, and made the data in a neutral format. And I got less code, instant change of settings and no dialog box!

Commonsware is right that the DB shouldn't hold formatting information.  However in general if you want to do work at the start of the app-  you show a spinner or other progress screen, and you ensure that you don't try to populate the normal display until that is done.  For example
public void onCreate() {
  if(needToDoLongRunningProcess()) {
    displayLoadingUI()
    doLongRunningProcess()
  }
  else {
    populateMainDisplay()
  }
}

public void doLongRunningProcess() {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    //doWhatever
    runOnUiThread({
      hideLoadingUI()
      populateMainDisplay()
    })
  }
}


When "the user's number format has changed" sounds alike a preference has changed. While a number-format is commonly used for string-formatting, therefore changes to the database are probably questionable - instead try to use onSharedPreferenceChanged() to update the GUI.
public class SomeActivity extends Activity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (this.mPrefs == null) {this.mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);}
        this.mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (this.mPrefs != null) {this.mPrefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);}
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(@NonNull SharedPreferences preferences, String key) {
        if (key != null && key.equals(Constants.PREFERENCE_KEY_NUMBER:FORMAT)) {

            /* TODO: update the GUI. */

            /* If it has to be: run a task. */
            Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executor.execute(() -> {
                
            });
        }
    }
}

